# How to determine if an array is saved in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, seed

In my seed.rb

```
  puts 'DEFAULT Categories'
  categories = Category.create([{name:'cat1'},{name:'cat2'}, {name: 'cat3'} ])
  if categories.save
    puts "categories saved"
  else
    puts "categories save failed"
  end
```

I use this to set the default categories
but the problem is that I can't `if categories.save` to see if all category item get saved and hence the seed.rb get passed
So, how can I see if an array get saved? (All of its elements)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if categories.all?(&:save)
  puts "categories saved"
else
  [...]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `create!` instead of `create`. It'll raise an an exception if it fails to save.

Comment: Much (if not most) of the time, blowing up the app with an exception because of a bad save is a bad idea.  Better to check if Model.save returned true or false and then render the errors if necessary.

Comment: For something user-facing, I would agree. But this is in a seed task.

Comment: very true.  In that case, blowing up the app during the seed might be what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

`.create` is creating the record.  So, when you get to your if statement nothing happening because the save already happened during the create.

Change your `.create` to a `.new`, and you will be able to check if the save happened successfully:

```
puts 'DEFAULT Categories'
categories = Category.new([{name:'cat1'},{name:'cat2'}, {name: 'cat3'} ])  
if categories.save  
  puts "categories saved"  
else  
  puts "categories save failed"  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if categories.all.each(&:persisted?)
  puts "categories saved"
else
  [...]
end
```